# Eclipse shortcut to run a class

Tags: java, eclipse, shortcut, launch

I have an Eclipse project where I often launch the same java class. I have added my run configuration to the favorites menu, but to launch it I still need to click on the run-drop-down menu and click the icon - is there any way to associate a shortcut to this? When I searched for it I got lost in all the plugins & other things which seemed to be not so simple.

edit: Let me clarify, I want something I can type the moment I start eclipse, regardless of what page I'm viewing, so no "run last" or "run current"; I want F12 to link to "launch foo.bar.MainClass".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should put in a feature request in the eclipse bug tracker (or vote up an existing equivalent feature request) or code it yourself.

Comment: Yeah, I'm pretty sure you can't assign shortcuts to launch configurations in Eclipse. Wish you could.

Answer (score 32):

Just use Ctrl + F11. (This is the standard keyboard shortcut to run the class you are working on)

I wish this is what you are looking for... buddy.

Comment: Where is documented this "standard"?

Answer (score 31):

- Open the workspace preferences by the menu: `Window > Preferences`
- Select from the tree: `Run/Debug > Launching`
- Now the `Launching` preferences are seen.
- At the bottom there is `Launch Operation`
- Use the option `Always launch the previously launched application`

Comment: This is the real answer. Thanks bro. I was struggling because my Eclipse, when the Run shortcut is hit, it always run my app as a standard Java application, not Maven Build, so basically nothing worked. It was a pain to always nagivate to the menu to just launch an application!!

Answer (score 26):

You can configure your launch behaviour so <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>F11</kbd> will launch the last launched application again, regardless of your current editor selection.

Look at "Run/Debug" - "Launching" within the eclipse preferences.

Comment: I know that, but that's not what I want.

Answer (score 6):

alt+shift+x+J  Rocks

Comment: +1 because it's what I would say too but it requires that the Main class is focused.

Answer (score 4):

You can go Window -> Preferences -> General -> Key and bind anything you want!I hope it helps!

Answer (score 3):

It is **Ctrl+F11**

Ctrl+Shift+X or Ctrl+Shift+J didn't worked for me!

Answer (score 1):

If you've added these classes to your favorite run configurations (available from the run/debug toolbar buttons as "Organize Favorites..."), then the shortcut key combo is Alt+R,T,1 to run your first favorite, Alt+R,T,2 to run your second, etc. Alt+R,H,# works for debug configs.

Answer (score 1):

on Windows machine
ctrl+Fn F11            ---        running
ctrl+Fn+Shift F11      ---        debugging

Answer (score 1):

If you are someone like me who wants to create a shortcut to run a class/program in java directly, you can create your own preferable shortcut in **ECLIPSE**!

****Follow these steps:****

`Window` > `Preferences` > `General` > `Keys`

1. Select **run** from `command` column
2. Enter your own shortcut in `Binding` section
3. **Apply and close!!**

**WARNING**: Make sure you don't create a shortcut which is already assigned for a different task!

Answer (score 0):

I cannot this the answer here but : CTRL+SHIFT+T do apparently exactly what you want! :) Maybe it's because you code it by yourself by time...

Watch here: http://eclipse.dzone.com/news/effective-eclipse-shortcut-key for more.

Answer (score 0):

I faced this problem in eclipse too. I have customized the configuration for me.

Windows -> preferances -> keys

Search for your configuration eg "Run Java Application" or just look for its icon.

Select it

and below in the binding field press keyboard keys which you want to add a shortcut for this configuration eg. ctrl + shift + T

and Apply

You are good to go use the same shortcut keys to whenever you need it.

Answer (score 0):

Just create an "External tool configuration" instead of a standard configuration for the class you want to run, and assign a shortcut key to "Run last launched external Tool".

Of course, there shall be no other external tool configuration.

Even if other java programs have been launched, or the current class contains a main() method, hitting the shortcut key will always run the same configured class.